# Magento 2.x issue with css and js files. Request resulting in 404

Tags: php, magento

According to my research this issue seems to be pretty popular in new Magento 2.x installations. Unfortunately no other question helped to resolve my issue.

I am running a PHP Server at 1&1 with PHP 7.0 Version and installed the latest Magento Community edition.

The setup-process went fine. But unfortunately no js or css resources can be loaded.

I already changed the `DriverInterface.php` and also updated all folders to 755 and files to 644 according to another answer.

I already also changed `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy` in the `di.xml`

my htaccess has / as rewritebase

Unfortunately the issue still persists.

If any1 has other ideas that might fix the issue I would gladly try them out.

Thank you for your time.

**update**

As suggested in an answer I  tried doing the following:

```
php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento cache:clean
php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy
```

The 1&1 Shared Webhosting should be running on PHP7 according to their interface, but when I type in `php -v` I get 4.4.9. Upon trying out different `php` calls I realized that the highest I can get is 5.5 with `php5.5`.

When typing `php5.5 bin/magento cache:clean` It tells me that it has to be run as cli.

After trying it with `php5.5-cli bin/magento cache:clean` I get an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in /homepages/41/d674471379/htdocs/dev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93
```

The line where the error is being thrown: `return new $type(...array_values($args));` so I assume that it can't interpret the `...`

Comment: yes you need 5.6
https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator

Comment: Any way to work around this when I can't manually implement 5.6 in a shared hosting enviroment?

Comment: i don't know
configure at your localhost and just upload on shared hosting maybe help but shared hosting it's not good idea for magento 2

Comment: unfortunately i have to work with the server that our client provides me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that changes in `pub/static/.htaccess` were required. The `RewriteBase` had to be changed to `/pub/static/`

Answer (score 1):

the files is present in pub/static folder? Disable all merge and minify options in core_config_data
try in console

```
php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento cache:clean
php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy
```

if it's not help provide more information about your error

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I updated my question accordingly.